# Show PHP process in a DIV without having to wait to finish via JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have two scripts

I want to send via jQUERY a form to a PHP file, and see in a DIV the process, but it waits until if finish to show all, and sometimes it can take a few seconds making the user thinks its not doing anything

Here is what I have

I have a form like this

```
<button type="button" id="agregarfotos"> Load</button>
<div id="respuesta"  style="width: 100%"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#agregarfotos').click(function() { 
    $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '../clases/class-album-procesar.php',
            data: $('#mainforma').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {

$('#respuesta').html(response);

          }); 
     });     
});
    </script>
```

And a PHP file named **class-album-procesar.php** with this:

```
<?php

ob_implicit_flush(1);
    for($i=0; $i<15; $i++){
    echo $i;

    //this is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
    echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

    sleep(1);
}

    ?>
```

If I run the **class-album-procesar.php** file by it self, I can see the numbers 1 to 14 one by one, like it should, but if I run it via the jquery file, it waits until the page is completed loaded to show the result

Is there a way to do this without having to wait until it finish?

Comment: why did you add a sleep function?

Comment: So it doesn't go to fast, to be able to see the code one by one

Comment: You should let javascript do the loop by using separate ajax calls

Comment: @EnterateNorte may be this article will help you out : http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/php/ajax-progress-php-script-without-polling/

Comment: @HastaDhana has the right answer. That's what I do a lot on my site, running a series of pings or port scans. Javascript calls each one separately on it's own schedule, and the PHP just does one function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the loop in php do it on jQuery.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    $.ajax({..});
}
```

This way you will be splitting the processing on multiple php processes, so instead of one long php script you have multiple short php scripts

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use third party jQuery library, but not sure that work fine.

Because, During ajax call PHP server busy with process. At that time server can't send any data to client. Server wait for finish that process and send data or information to client with request status 200.